# Unable to compile the com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.base.Optional package of gwt-dev jar

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to use the Optional class of guava jar. I am able to use it in my project.But, in the gwt-dev jar the Optional class has already been there in the package  `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.base.Optional`. So, I don't want to use the guava jar for just using the Optional class. So, I am trying to use the Optional class of gwt-dev jar.

Steps which I have done:

- I have created `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.base` package in my project
- In that package I have created the Base.gwt.xml file.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- semi-autogenerated module descriptor -->
  <module>
     <source path="">
   </source>
  </module>
  ```
- I have included the Base.gwt.xml file in my gwt.xml file.

Though I have done the above steps I was not able to compile the code. I am getting the below exception:

No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.base.Optional; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Any suggestions would be appretiated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.*` - those are internally repackaged jars. There's no guarantee they'll be there in the next version of GWT - in fact, I'd expect them (at least the Guava part) to be removed in favor of "vanilla" Guava, [as suggested in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/IVZy0sRxmeE). To further reinforce this there's no source attached for them in the gwt-dev.jar (as you've experienced), so you can't use them in your client-side code.

Please use the normal dependency on Google Guava - the GWT compiler will *only* compile in the parts of Guava that you are using (especially if you just inherit `com.google.common.base.Base`) and prune out the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have imported Google Guava jar to use the Optional pattern.

Comment: Hello Klimer, I would like to know one more thing. Is there any way to use the gwt-dev files in our project without creating a seperate gwt.xml file which corresponds to the gwt-dev package. In should won't there any seperate gwt.xml files for the packages in gwt-dev project which I can use in my project?

Comment: You can use classes from the gwt-dev.jar in your project without any extra configuration (for example to create a [Generator](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html#generator-implementation)), but I can't think of any class from there that you can use in your client-side code. `gwt-dev.jar` contains classes from the GWT compiler, DevMode, etc.